# Finding matching data in a column in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets namely, (Sheet2) & (Sheet3). I would like to match the data in column A of sheet 2 from column A of sheet 3. Example below:

```
Sheet2  Sheet3
StdID   StdID
1001    1001
1002    1002
1003    1002
1004    1004
1005    1005
1006    1006
```

I want the output to be like this.. (There's already a Sheet4 but it's blank so there's no need for a vba code for adding a new sheet.)

```
Sheet2  Sheet3  Sheet4
StdID   StdID   Result
1001    1001    Yes
1002    1002    Yes
1003    1002    No
1004    1004    Yes
1005    1005    Yes
1006    1006    Yes
```

Comment: Why not just use a countif formula to show if it exists or not?

Comment: I don't know how to use count in vba :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using simple `if()` function.
Formula in `Sheet4` would be..

```
=IF(Sheet2!A2=Sheet3!B2,"Yes","No")
```

**By using VBA:**

```
Public Sub dataMatch()
Dim lnCell As Long
    lnCell = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

        For i = 2 To lnCell
            If Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & i) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i) Then
                Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & i) = "Yes"
            Else
                Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & i) = "No"
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Assume you data start from `A2` cell in every sheet, `A1` cell is used as header. Result will display in `Sheet4` `A2` cell. If you to show it in another column means in `B` or `C` then modify codes as your own.

Comment: Answer is given as your expected output.

Comment: Thank You but How could I do it in vba? I'm sorry I forgot to say it that it should be a vba code :(

Comment: Lastly, ahm how could I pull out those data who has a "No" tag? I mean I want to see it's list in another column but still with the same sheet.